# Call Oracle stored procedure from Java App using hibernate and c3p0 connection pool

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm not able to find a way to do something that seems to me as a common task.

I have

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS OBJECT (field1 int, field2 int);
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TEST (obj IN MyType) AS ....
```

How can I call this procedure from Java application ? I'm using hibernate and c3p0 connection pool that hides native jdbc connection, so I cannot cast its proxy connection to OracleConnection. I found that c3p0 has rawConnectionOperation, but I don't understand how to accomplish my task using it.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has a similar problem, it can be solved like :

```
public class CallSPTest
{
   public static STRUCT createSTRUCT(oracle.sql.StructDescriptor structDescriptor, 
    java.sql.Connection connection, java.lang.Object[] objects) 
    throws java.sql.SQLException
    {
       return new STRUCT(structDescriptor,connection,objects);
    }
    public void testSP(Session s)
    {
       t = s.beginTransaction();
       s.doWork(new Work()
        {

            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException
            {
                try
                {
                    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("call SP_TEST(?)");                       
                    final Object[] values = new Object[]{1,2};

                    java.sql.Connection connect = 
  org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.getWrappedConnection(connection);
                    C3P0ProxyConnection castCon = (C3P0ProxyConnection) connect;
                    Method m = StructDescriptor.class.getMethod("createDescriptor", new Class[]{ String.class,Connection.class});
                    Object[] args = new Object[]{"MyType",C3P0ProxyConnection.RAW_CONNECTION};
                    StructDescriptor desc1 =(StructDescriptor) castCon.rawConnectionOperation(m, null, args);

                    Method m2 = CallSPTest.class.getMethod("createSTRUCT",
                            new Class[]{StructDescriptor.class, Connection.class,Object[].class});

                    args = new Object[] {desc1,C3P0ProxyConnection.RAW_CONNECTION,values};
                    final STRUCT struct1 = (STRUCT)castCon.rawConnectionOperation(m2,null,args);
                    cs.setObject(1, struct1, Types.STRUCT);
                    int aff_rows = cs.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != t)
        {
            t.rollback();                
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it in a SQL prompt you can do it in Hibernate with

```
session.createSQLQuery("exec SP_TEST([yourargs]");
```

I'm not familiar with custom types in Oracle but use the same syntax you would use in a query.

Comment: The problem is with arguments. To properly assign them I have to use classes from `oracle.sql` package (STRUCT, StructDescriptor) which work only with `OracleConnection`, but c3p0 proxy connection cannot be cast to `OracleConnection` which looks like a vicious circle to me.