# Passing user defined list from hibernate to oracle stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, orm

I want to pass a user defined object from my hibernate class and pass it onto a stored procedure which reads this list of objects and does the processing. How can i do the same?

The Class is as follows.

```
public class ExcelListenerBean {
    private int id;
    private String shortName;
    private String fmrCusip;
    private Double incorrectTrdShares;
    private Double incorrectTrdPrice;
    private String incorrectTrdBuySell;
    private Double incorrectTrdCommRate;
    private Double incorrectTrdCommission;
    private Double incorrectTrdFees;
    private Double incorrectTrdNet;
    private Double correctionTrdShares;
    private Double correctionTrdPrice;
    private String correctionTrdBuySell;
    private Double correctionTrdCommRate;
    private Double correctionTrdCommission;
    private Double correctionTrdFees;
    private Double correctionTrdNet;
    private String currency;
    private String fx;
    private Double netUSD;
    private String notes;
}
```

Can any one please let me know how to draft the procedure and how to loop through the list of ExcelListenerBean objects and save them to a table.

Comment: Can anyone please give me the code snippet to outline the stored procedure, basically iterating over array of TableOfExcelListenerBean objects. I am pretty new to SP and have troubles in writing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create OBJECT type , say `MyType is OBJECT ....` in Oracle that has all the fields you need
2. Create collection type , `TableOfMyObject IS TABLE OF MyObjectType`
3. Create procedure that takes `TableOfMyObject` as parameter.

You can use collection variable in SQL statements in your stored procedure like 
`SELECT * FROM TABLE(collection_variable)`

I did the same, but the biggest challenge wast to call it from the app using hibernate - [I finally found the way to do that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819104/call-oracle-stored-procedure-from-java-app-using-hibernate-and-c3p0-connection-p)

**Update** 
SQL that can be run from Toad.

```
set serveroutput on; -- for debugging, 
-- it makes sense if your procedure outputs anything
declare my_list TableOfMyObject  := TableOfMyObject ();
begin 
  my_list.extend;
  my_list(1) := MyType([MyType constructor parameters]);

  my_list.extend;
  my_list(2) := MyType([MyType constructor parameters]);
  your_procedure(my_list);
end;
```

Comment: Can you let me know how to execute the procedure that takes TableOfMyObject as parameter from TOAD or SQL+

Comment: @sandy : see update. the code puts 2 elements into collection and calls procedure.