# Passing a list of values to a stored procedure using JPA 2.1 / Hibernate 4

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a stored procedure that takes in a *list of strings* (and follows limitations on stored procedures, [according to Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#sp_query)):

```
PROCEDURE count_active_esc(p_count OUT NUMBER, p_codes IN string_list);
```

where `string_list` is a custom type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(100)
```

and want to to call it from JPA entity manager ([a new feature in JPA 2.1](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Stored_Proc/StoredProcedures.html#)).

I tried to use an array:

```
StoredProcedreQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("count_active_esc");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_count", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_codes", String[].class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.setParameter("p_codes", new String[] { "AEST" });

query.getOutputParameterValue("p_count"); // <<<<< throws an exception
```

and got an exception:

```
    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'COUNT_ACTIVE_ESC'
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

And if I pass in a list:

```
StoredProcedreQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("count_active_esc");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_count", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_codes", List.class, ParameterMode.IN); // <<<<< throws an exception
query.setParameter("p_codes", new ArrayList<String> {{ "AEST" }});

query.getOutputParameterValue("p_count");
```

it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null`

Also adding `query.setHint("org.hibernate.callable", "true")` didn't help.

What is the correct way of doing this in JPA or Hibernate? Is it at all possible without resorting to JDBC?

Environment: JPA 2.1, Hibernate 4.3.5, Oracle

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: AFAIK Hibernate doesn't custom types in SP calls. So I had to use plain JDBC. Also [EclipseLink's PLSQLStoredProcedureCall](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/StoredProcedures#PLSQLStoredProcedureCall_-_Complex_data) seems to do the trick.

Comment: Yes - I arrived at a similar conclusion, in fact - neither Hibernate nor the JPA standard seem to support complex SQL types explicitly: *"JPA does not support object-relational data-types, but some JPA providers may offer some support"* ([see here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics)). (Note that EclipseLink/TopLink does provide basic support). My solution to the problem was different, though - I used PostgreSQL's built-in functions (`array_to_string` and `string_to_array` respectively) to sneak the arrays I was trying to pass through as simple `VARCHAR` values.

Comment: @PriiduNeemre, would you care to share your solution?

Comment: Hi.. is it still a limitation.. I am trying to have similar array of varchar type as OUT variable.. I am getting same error as u have specified. what is the final solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an update on this. We switched to MyBatis for stored procedure calls.
It has a much better support for custom database types (via custom type handlers) and works well for us. If it's an option for you, see this example https://programmer.help/blogs/mybatis-passes-the-list-parameter-to-call-the-oracle-stored-procedure.html
Hope it helps

Comment: Something similar to your issue I hope,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973167/passing-user-defined-list-from-hibernate-to-oracle-stored-procedure

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java

Answer (score -1):

Change Integer.class to Types.INTEGER

Comment: will not work as of the following : StoredProcedureQuery javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(String arg0, Class arg1, ParameterMode arg2)